# Getting unexpected space after menu in mobile view for my wordpress site?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have created one wordpress website and this is website for the educational purposes and before making changes i have added subheader to each page and simple make it display:none but after making that changes in desktop view it is showing perfectly but in the mobile view it will show some extra space after the menu as you can see by visiting this is my website link.
http://demo.proserindustries.com/ , what i can do such that this uexpected space will get removed.?

Answer (score 0):

Your .navbar-nav class adds 7.5px of margin to your navbar.

Add this to your CSS

```
.navbar-nav {
    margin: 0 -15px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't understood my problem, open http://demo.proserindustries.com/ this url in mobile and check there is space after menu bar that was my exact problem facing and i want solution for it ?

Comment: I'm sorry - I thought you were talking about the little gap between header and opened menu.It is kind of hard as 'space after menu bar' could mean quite a lot of things. Can you please give some more detail on where exactly your Problem is? Maybe send a screenshot or show the code where the problem occurs?

Comment: You can see screenshot by click on https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vHH5prZCw-14WNTF0Jx-bc-qAaH55J8k  in that you will see gap after menu in mobile view , how can i remove it ?

Comment: ok wow - that's quite the gap. I could not replicate the problem on my end sorry. For me the site works just fine, without that. Try using Google Chrom with Remote Debugging to get a better understanding of what might be causing the bug. Here is a good guide on how to do so: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/
I'm sorry but I dont't think I can help you any further as I can't replicate the bug